# Making sequence of fixed-width <div>s display in rows by four

Tags: php, css, sql

I have this code:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; display:block; width: 916px; overflow: auto;">
                <?php echo "";


     echo "<i>Owned: $line->phone </i><br><br>";

            $query = "SELECT person_id, person.name, person.sex, person.father_id, person.mother_id,PhotosComp.reference as reference
FROM person

WHERE person.id=$currId";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {    
            while ($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {



     echo "<div valign='top'>";

                 echo "";


            echo "<img src=".$line->reference." style=float:left; height='50px' border='1'>"; 

                    echo "";
                    echo "<a href='details.php?id=$line->person_id'>";
                    echo "<b>";
                    echo "$line->name</a>";
                    echo "</b>, <font size='-2'>(";
                    echo "$line->sex";
                    echo ", </font><font size='-2'>";
                    echo "$line->father_id";
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "$line-mother_id";
                    echo "<br>";
                            echo "</div>";          
                }

            }echo "";
        ?>
      </div>
```

The info is shown correctly vertical… but I would like to show lets say 4 results horizontal before it breaks into new line.

So I get this result from the database as it is now:

```
PICTURE  Bob  
         Mick   
         Jane

PICTURE  Roy  
         Mack   
         June

PICTURE  Mia  
         Roy    
         Jane

PICTURE  Lou  
         Bob    
         June

PICTURE  Bib  
         Mock   
         Jine

PICTURE  Beb  
         Muck   
         Jone

PICTURE  Ray  
         Rob    
         Mia
```

And would like it to be shown as this:

```
PICTURE  Bob          PICTURE  Roy        PICTURE  Mia       PICTURE  Lou
         Mick                  Mack                Roy                Bob
         Jane                  June                Jane               June

PICTURE  Bob          PICTURE  Roy        PICTURE  Mia       
         Mick                  Mack                Roy             
         Jane                  June                Jane
```

The results from DB can be 0 to 15–20. I don’t need any upper limit.

Comment: is it your code working ? ....

Comment: Count the results, add `style="float: left;"` until the result hits `% 4 == 0` then add `style="clear: both;"`

Comment: as i said i need some good explanations... when you say "count the results"... ill start pointing at the screen going 1 -2 -3 LOL

Comment: btw the output code might not be 100% correct, but it is correct at the site. The problem is how to get the <div>s to show horizontal not more than 4 at a time before breaking to new row :)

Comment: @CMilla Why don’t you cut & paste the code you actually use? You should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: because its a paid script and i dont want anyone to google it and steal it :P  but i havent removed anything important regarding my question anyway so it shouldnt matter regarding the div tags

Comment: @CMilla Your script is definitely not working. At least after the `$query` definition you miss closing quote and semicolon. Really read the MCVE help page I linked to.

Comment: ok ive edited it now... 

But if i just could get a better explanation from @DanFromGermany i could test this...

Comment: @CMilla Sorry, your code still does not satisfy the *Readable* condition. Please, do not use tabs, replace them by four spaces. Also use indentation consistently. When posting hard-to-read, incomplete, broken-in-ways-unrelated-to-the-question code, your question is useless for future visitors. Such questions are not much valued around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some scaffolding like this might get you closer to your goal. as @DanFromGermany explained, you need to `clear:both` underneath your div elements. Try not to put style tags in your markup, unless your page is super optimised or something.

markup

```
while($result) {
    echo "<div class=\"span-3\">";
    echo "<div>";
    echo "the content father->id line->person_id etc etc";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}

echo "<div class=\"clear-fix\"></div>";
```

css

```
.span-3 { 
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    margin:0; padding: 0;
}

.span-3 > div {
    margin: 10px; /* or some other value */
}

.clear-fix {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: yes this got my way closer :) ill play around with this and see if i get it 100% as i want it :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this , let me know if it works .

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
{    

    $counter    = 0;   

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
    {


        if($counter %4 != 0) 
        {
            #this will break your div  
            echo "<div valign='top' style='clear:both;'>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div valign='top' style='float:left;display:block;'>";
        }


        //if ($line->reference = (NULL)) { echo "<img src=".$line->reference." style=float:left; height='50px' border='1'>"; 
        //else echo "<img src='../temp_pic.jpg' style=float:left; height='50px' border='1'>";}
        echo "";
        echo "<a href='page.php?id=$line->person_id'>";
        echo "<b>";
        echo "$line->name</a>";
        echo "</b><br>";


        echo "line->father_id";
        echo"<br>";
        echo "line->mother_id";

        $counter++;

    }
    echo "</div>";          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic bit of code to show pictures in the format you require. You will need to change this to match up with your `while loop` and also change the clases and css code to match your requirements ie page width etc.

```
<style>
html {width:100%; background:#ffffff;}
body {max-width: 960px; background:red; margin:0 auto;}
img {max-width: 225px; height: auto;}
.clear {clear:both;}
.no-margin{margin:0 !important;}
.margin-right {margin-right: 20px;}
</style>


<div class="pic-wrap">
<?php
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';
$pictures[] = 'http://www.canoefoundation.org.uk/cf/assets/Image/Yellow%20Duck.jpg';


$count = count($pictures);
$i=1;
foreach($pictures as $picture)
{
  if($i % 4 == 0)
  {
    echo '<img src="'.$picture.'" class="no-margin four">';
  }
  elseif($i == $count)
  {
    echo '<img src="'.$picture.'" class="margin-right">';
    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<img src="'.$picture.'" class="margin-right">';

  }
  $i++;
}
?>
</div>
```

Here is an image of the output

[image]

Much like @DanFromGermany mentioned this clears floats and also adds a clear at the end by using a count of the results.

```
$count = count($pictures);
```

It then determines the last result form this

```
elseif($i == $count)
```

With `$i` being incremented on each iteration of the loop.

```
$i++;
```

Hope this helps.